# Build fire sdk is not working

Tags: buildfire

[Build fire sdk](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk) not working. Cloned the latest version of SDK. The web server used: Apache2 (Tried with nginx too). After clicking on "StartDeveloping" it takes to this url "localhost/buildfire/pluginTester/index.html#/plugin/myPlugin".

Error message from google chrome console:

```
angular.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ui-bootstrap.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular-route.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
    at angular-route.min.js:7
    at angular-route.min.js:14
ng-file-upload.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at ng-file-upload.min.js:2
ui-bootstrap.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ng-map.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at ng-map.min.js:1
ngAutocomplete.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at ngAutocomplete.js:11
angulargrid.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
    at angulargrid.js:42
    at angulargrid.js:22
    at angulargrid.js:24
angular-color-picker.js:130 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
    at angular-color-picker.js:130
    at angular-color-picker.js:13
    at angular-color-picker.js:15
app.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at app.js:4
shellCtrl.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
    at shellCtrl.js:6
indexCtrl.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
    at indexCtrl.js:5
settingsCtrl.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
    at settingsCtrl.js:5
gdprService.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined
    at gdprService.js:1
loginCtrl.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
    at loginCtrl.js:1
app.min.js:4 httpClient is loading
app.min.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
    at app.min.js:22
web.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'directive' of undefined
    at web.min.js:1
app.min.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentUser' of undefined
    at new UserDatastoreAPI (app.min.js:9)
    at PluginAPI.init (app.min.js:20)
    at new PluginAPI (app.min.js:20)
    at overrides.js:7
app.min.js:1 !! Post Master:: Ignore Invalid packet SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at postMessageHandler (app.min.js:1) setImmediate$0.4189524352329266$1
app.min.js:13 audioPlayer localStorage error TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of null
    at Object.init (app.min.js:13)
    at app.min.js:13
init @ app.min.js:13
/images/favicon-32x32.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/images/favicon-16x16.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
util.js:224 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
ax.j @ util.js:224
util.js:224 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
ax.j @ util.js:224
```

Please fix the issues on the sdk. I have tested this in two machines and two versions of the sdk. Same error.

Comment: Have you tried using the BuildFire SDK CLI? It will greatly simplify your experience with the BuildFire SDK. https://www.npmjs.com/package/buildfire-cli

Comment: I was able to clone the SDK repo and run the tester using http-server just now on a new machine, and it worked as expected. I'd still suggest using the SDK CLI, but if you're still having trouble perhaps you can provide more details of the specific steps that you took.

Comment: I am running nginx and another dev is running apache2. Ubuntu and MacOS respectively. Cloned the repo, the latest one. Still, the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the CLI?

Comment: We identified an issue related to Linux, which has since been resolved. Be sure to get the latest version. (We tested with Nginx to confirm.)